# How can I access my data outside particular scope in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
   //declaring the module
   var app = angular.module("sachin", ["ng-fusioncharts"]);
    //declaring a factory  
    app.factory('team',function(){
    return {
            runs_aus : ''
        };
    });

    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$http,team){
        $scope.australia=[];    
        $scope.total_runs_aus=0;
        //fetching data from JSON
        $http.get("convertcsv.json").then(function(response){
        $scope.sachin_data=response.data;
        angular.forEach($scope.sachin_data, function(value, key){
             // manipulating data
            if (value.opposition=="v Australia"){
            if (value.batting_score=="-"|| value.batting_score == "TDNB" || value.batting_score == "DNB")
                $scope.total_runs=$scope.total_runs;
            else if (value.batting_score.substr(value.batting_score.length - 1) == "*"){
                value.batting_score = value.batting_score.substr(1);
                $scope.total_runs_aus+=parseInt(value.batting_score,10)
            }
            else
                $scope.total_runs_aus+=parseInt(value.batting_score,10);

        });
        $scope.australia.push({ runs:$scope.total_runs_aus});
        team.runs_aus=$scope.total_runs_aus;
        //got final result in $scope.total_runs_aus
        console.log(team.runs_aus);
        //printing inside the scope(works fine)
        });
        console.log(team.runs_aus);
        //printing outside the scope(can't access)
```

- I am trying to access the total runs scored outside the
  then(function()) of the get request
- first I tried global variables in javascript
- Now I tried using a factory Any help would be    appreciated

Comment: You are working with asynchronous data. Move the logic that uses the totalRuns variable in to the then() function as well. The console logs are being executed before the promise is resolved so the data is not available.

Comment: Consider using promise chains if you want specific code to execute after the `$http.get` request is resolved. See an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24360864/5304361

Comment: do you understand what I am suggesting? For example, move your console logs underneath the if else block inside the .then() function. The code inside the then() will execute when the `$http.get()` is done executing. Given the location of your console logs, these are executed before the data is available.

Comment: can promise chaining be used? I am adding another .then(console.log("test")); after the first http.get("url").then(#code).then(console.log("test")); but doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service to store that data:

```
app.service('MyService', function() {

    var self = {
        'myString': 1,
        'myObject': {},
        'myArray': [],
        'doSomething': function(param) {
            self.myString = param
        },
        'anotherFunction': function() {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return self;

});
```

You just need to inject `MyService` on your controller and access it like `MyService.myObject = something`.

Comment: This is not going to work because it has nothing to do with Asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 1):

The important part to understand is that you are working **async** operations. The code continues to execute and prints your console logs even though the data has not been returned from `$http.get()`. Your code needs to account for this and run the code that operates on the data after its been resolved.

.then() expects a function as the parameter of the method signature. For example:

```
$http.get("convertcsv.json").then(function(response){
    $scope.sachin_data=response.data;
}).then(function() {
    console.log('Value in scope:', $scope.sachin_data);
});
```

or

```
function processData = function() {
    console.log('Value in scope:', $scope.sachin_data);
};

$http.get("convertcsv.json").then(function(response){
    $scope.sachin_data=response.data;
}).then(processData);
```

or chain multiple promises together (you must add angular's $q as a dependency):

```
function processData1 = function(data) {

    //Create a deferred object.
    var defer = $q.defer();

    //Do something with data.
    console.log('Value in scope:', data);

    //Pass data to next promise in promise chain.
    defer.resolve(data);

    //Resolve data to be returned.
    return defer.promise;
};

function processData2 = function(data) {

    //Create a deferred object.
    var defer = $q.defer();

    //Do something else with data.
    console.log('Value in scope:', data);

    //Pass data to next promise in promise chain.
    defer.resolve(data);

    //Resolve data to be returned.
    return defer.promise;
};



$http.get("convertcsv.json")
     .then(processData1)
     .then(processData2);
```

Please have a look at:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/
- https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns

The code as is may have syntax errors as it has not been tested. Links are general reference and not specific to $q but the concepts are consistent.