# JavaScript Method Chaining or Angular $q

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, method-chaining

I am relatively new to JavaScript, and would appreciate your patience.

I am trying to chain my method calls to run asynchronously, but am a bit stuck.

I have done a lot of searching and tried various methods, but I am missing something.

The idea is to call one method after the other, but only once the first method has resolved.

I am using `AngularJs`, and **I am not sure whether to use `$q` and `$defer`, or simple method chaining**, or something completely different...

**I have seen the below method of chaining:**

```
callFirst()
.then(function(firstResult){
   return callSecond();
})
.then(function(secondResult){
   return callThird();
})
.then(function(thirdResult){
   //Finally do something with promise, or even return this
});
```

**And this example of using `$q`:**

```
app.service("githubService", function ($http, $q) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    this.getAccount = function () {
        return $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/haroldrv')
            .then(function (response) {
                // promise is fulfilled
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
                // promise is returned
                return deferred.promise;
            }, function (response) {
                // the following line rejects the promise 
                deferred.reject(response);
                // promise is returned
                return deferred.promise;
            })
        ;
    };
});
```

**Below is my main function, and which method would be best for my purposes, and how would I implement the best solution?**

**NOTE:** At this stage in my `controller`, my data has already been returned from my `API` call, and I am simply using the data to populate graphs and data grids:

```
function formatDataAccordingToLocation(dataFromAPI) {

    $scope.dataModel = DataModelService.dataLoaded();

    dataFromAPI.then(function (data) {

        $scope.totalItems = data.total_tweet_count;

        if ($scope.volumeChartChanged) {

            $scope.volumeChartChange = false;

            configureVolumeChart(data);

        }

        else {
            setSummaryPageData(data);

            setTweetListPageData(data);

            configureVolumeChart(data);

            configureMostMentionedGraph(data);

            configureFollowerGrowthGraph(data);

            configureEngagementsGraph(data);

            configureHashtagsGraph(data);

            configureTweetsVsReTweetsGraph(data);

            configureWordCloudGraph(data);
        }
    })
}
```

I know I am asking a lot, and would be very grateful for your help.

**Research and resources:**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

[Chain promises with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357445/chain-promises-with-angularjs)

https://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html

Comment: You need not use $q for promises in Angular, $http itself returns a promise, so you can chain `$http.then()` where each of them will be called after the previous one is resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do I need to chain my main function at all (data was already returned from my service), or do I simply call one function after the other as per my code?

Comment: Is your "dataFromApi" a promise ? or what exactly you want to do ? You want to call each of those functions one after the other ?

Comment: The "dataFromApi", is my actual json data already returned. I want to know what would be the best method to call my functions in my main method "formatDataAccordingToLocation". One after another, or chain them, or something else?

Comment: In order to chain function calls, all those functions should be created as promise ($q example), then call it as in your first example. Actually why you need to implement this? I dont see a point of creating promise functions and call one after another.

Comment: I.e., would it be OK and acceptable to keep my `formatDataAccordingToLocation` method as it is and call the functions synchronously, as i am not waiting for an API call to return data?

Comment: Yes. your code is fine. You don't have to make them promises and chain the requests as there are no i/o calls that delays the execution.

Comment: Yes, because you are calling all those functions inside $http success return. (ie inside "then") so there is no problem.

Comment: Thank you all - much appreciated. Always great to learn from you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the great feedback and comments from Paulson Peter and suzo, the following would be the answer to my question:

**As my main function (`formatDataAccordingToLocation`)is inside my returned successful  `$http` call, there is no need for me to chain these method calls with promises, and in doing so, delaying my execution.**